# How can I do a dropdown menu as a picker view with an "other" option that uses a keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu, swift3, keyboard

Please help! Im a huge beginner to programming.

I currently have an alert controller set up to enter text into a label when I tap on a button. I am trying to find a quicker way to enter text with preloaded words from a dropdown menu, instead of typing them in. I've seen online that you can do this with a [pickerview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGr7qsKGkzY) or with [labels/buttons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqFD3DiWwAQ).

My issue is that I would like to have the option to write in my own text, if by chance, I didn't program the right preloaded words. Im a complete noob to Xcode/swift so my best guess is somehow (no idea how) integrating my text-button alert-controller as a button in my dropdown menu, or vice versa, where my dropdown menu is an option in my alert controller? This is the alert controller used to enter text into a label when a button is clicked:

```
//Text button

@IBOutlet weak var TextLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func TextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Text Button Tapped")
    openTextAlert()
}

func openTextAlert() {
    //Create Alert Controller
    let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Whatever Text Your Heart Desires:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //Create Cancel Action
    let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    alert9.addAction(cancel9)

    //Create OK Action
    let ok9 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
        let textfield = alert9.textFields?[0]
        print(textfield?.text!)
        self.TextLabel.text = textfield?.text!
    }

    alert9.addAction(ok9)

    //Add Text Field
    alert9.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
        textfield.placeholder = "Whatever text you want to enter"
    }

    //Present Alert Controller
    self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am not directly using textfields in my app as the heigh of the field is too large.
Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you add an image an what problem you are facing or what exactly do you want?

Comment: [I want a button to tap that lets me select from a variety of words that will show up on a label](http://codewithchris.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/img/uipickerview/UIPickerView_simulator_SwiftBlog.jpg).
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [I need to also have an option to write in my own unique words into that label - as i have already coded.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=uialertcontroller&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt996a0KDSAhUH9YMKHT0bCrMQ_AUICCgB&biw=1363&bih=761#imgrc=dgFKg8Peh7F57M:)

Comment: You can use this control (https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQDropDownTextField) instead.

Comment: Yes but how would I make the textfield outlet an action in my alert controller?